# django start celery daemon in production with supervisor

Tags: python, django, celery, supervisord

I have created a conf file for supervisor inside `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/myproject-celery.conf`

My configuration file looks like:

```
[program:celery]
command=/var/www/html/project/venv/bin/python  /var/www/html/project/manage.py celeryd --loglevel=INFO
environment=PYTHONPATH=/var/www/html/project
directory=/var/www/html/project
user=www-data
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celeryd.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
priority=998
```

Here in my productin I want to start celery. For that I am doing

```
supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/myproject-celery.conf
```

When I do this it says

```
Error: .ini file does not include supervisord section
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: don;t load the conf.d files as your main conf file for supervisor. see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing you [supervisord] section in your config file, but that is likely because you are not loading the main conf file

see [docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#supervisord-section-settings)

You should not start `supervisord` with -c and a conf.d file - the files in that folder are usually loaded automatically. Usually, the `-c` is reserved for when your have a conf you created elsewhere other than the normal directory.

If you start supervisord without a -c, it should load your `/etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf` file

Your conf file should look something like this:

```
; supervisor config file

[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

as you can see it automatically loads all the conf files in your conf.d folder

Comment: You mean I should not do anything, myproject-celery.conf file will automatically be loaded and celery will start ?

Comment: yes, your main conf file should have as it's last line a command that loads all conf files in the conf.d directory

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. How can I know that my celery process is running ? LIke  python manage.py celeryd --loglever=INFO in local

Comment: you can use `supervisorctl` to see current status of processes as well as manage them - http://supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisorctl

Comment: Did that fix the issue?