# Run Celery in production with Supervisor

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, celery, supervisord

I am trying to launch `Celery v3.1.25` in production. As I have found in [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.0/userguide/daemonizing.html#supervisor) 
there are 4 ways to run it, 1 of them is to use `Supervisor`. I have used it before - my Django project is running using it. I made following steps:
1. Created `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/mycelery.conf` on the basics of [official git repo](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/extra/supervisord/).

```
[program:mycelery]
command=celery worker -A cosmetics_crawler_project --loglevel=INFO
directory=/home/chiefir/polo/Cosmo
user=chiefir
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/chiefir/logs/celery/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/home/chiefir/logs/celery/celery.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopasgroup=true
priority=1000
```

2. Created `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/mycelerybeat.conf`:

```
[program:mycelerybeat]
command=celery beat -A cosmetics_crawler_project --schedule /var/lib/celery/beat.db --loglevel=INFO
directory=/home/chiefir/polo/Cosmo
user=chiefir
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/chiefir/logs/celery/celerybeat.log
stderr_logfile=/home/chiefir/logs/celery/celerybeat.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopasgroup=true
priority=999
```

3. And my `/etc/supervisord.conf` is set to:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket    

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

I have found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31656717/8495108) that I have to run `supervisord` to fire the Celery, but it throws error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/supervisord", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('supervisor==3.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'supervisord')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 367, in main
    go(options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 377, in go
    d.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/supervisord.py", line 77, in main
    info_messages)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py", line 1388, in make_logger
    stdout = self.nodaemon,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/loggers.py", line 346, in getLogger
    handlers.append(RotatingFileHandler(filename,'a',maxbytes,backups))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/loggers.py", line 172, in __init__
    FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/loggers.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.stream = open(filename, mode)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log'
```

More confusing here is why does it try to use `python2.7` if I have my project running in `python 3.5`? And what should I do further cuz there is so small information in the official Celery docs about that.
**UPDATE 1:**  If I run `supervisord` as a `root` user.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:297: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
  'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
Error: Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.  Shut this program down first before starting supervisord.For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Might be there a problems with wrong supervisor installation? I have found [here](https://medium.com/@channeng/celery-scheduler-part-2-managing-celery-with-supervisor-2a0c6e7f7a6e) that I have install supervisor like this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y supervisor
pip install supervisor==3.3.3
```

But I have done only first part, and with that my project works (without Celery, obviously). Should I also install supervisor with pip?
**UPDATE 3** When i tried to recipe from update 2 - i got a message that it is impossible to use `pip install supervisor` with python 3+ :/

```
Supervisor requires Python 2.4 or later but does not work on any version of Python 3.  You are using version 3.5.2
```

Comment: Meybe the file is owned by `root` go to the path and try to change onwnership.. with `sudo chown username -R folder_or_file_name`.. Where `username` is the username and `folder_or_file_name` is the folder's name.

Comment: @Lemayzeur I tried that - see my update 1. It still tries to run `supervisor` from python 2.7, may be this is an issue?

Comment: @Chiefir, its better to install celery and supervisor in virtual environment rather install it globally in system. Update all paths in supervisor programs relative to your virtual environment

Comment: try uninstall python2  since you're not using it

Comment: @Lemayzeur how can I do that? I am so newbie at Linux and deployment :)

Comment: If you'are using `virtualenv`, all commands are running under python2 because you had created that virtual env with python2... to create your virtual env with python3.* run this command `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.* --distribute env_name` where `*` is your python version.

Comment: if you want to uninstall python **As far I know, it's not recommended to remove the default python** run this command `sudo apt autoremove python2.*`

Comment: @Lemayzeur I have created my venv with `virtualenv . --python=$(which python3.5)`. Is that wrong?

Comment: correct! it should work

Comment: @Lemayzeur but that still does not work :/ Can you please see my update 2?

Comment: @Lemayzeur OMG, finally one of the recipes from one of tutorials worked. Thanks for help anyway :)